# How to update layer in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a question about mapbox -- update feature on layer.

At first, I have an initial GeoJSON, and they can show on the map
[image]

We can see the variable "user" on the console and the two points on the map.

Now I query data from my local database, and backend transfers GEOJSON to frontend, the variable "user" has been updated, as we can see from the console.

[image]

So, now the layer should be updated, 
I write a click function that when I click the old layer(points) the new data(points) will show.

```
map.on('load', function(){

        map.addSource('wifiData',{
            'type': "geojson",
            'data': {
                    "type": "FeatureCollection",
                    "features": user,
                }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'test',
            'type': 'circle',
            'source' : 'wifiData',
            'paint':{
                'circle-color': '#00b7bf',
                'circle-radius': [
                    '/',['get','total'],50
                ],
                'circle-stroke-width': 1,
                'circle-stroke-color': '#333',
                'circle-opacity': 0.3,
            }
        });

map.on('click','test',function () {
                map.getSource('wifiData').setData(user);
            })

        });
```

But console shows "Error {message: "Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object." "
could you tell me how to update the layer on the map depends on the new data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid GeoJSON. If you have multiple features you need to wrap them up in a feature collection